# investigate contents of a sqlite3 file

Tags: sqlite, dump

I have created a new, clean `firefox` profile from scratch, and added couple of bookmarks. These, I have learned, are stored in `places.sqlite` file inside the profile directory. This file seems to be too big (1.2 MB) and I am wondering why:

```
$ ls -lh places.sqlite 
-rw------- 1 martin martin 1.2M Sep  8 07:24 places.sqlite
```

When I open it with `sqlite3` from the commandline, I see there are couple of tables:

```
$ sqlite3 places.sqlite 
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
sqlite> .tables
moz_anno_attributes  moz_favicons         moz_items_annos    
moz_annos            moz_historyvisits    moz_keywords       
moz_bookmarks        moz_hosts            moz_places         
moz_bookmarks_roots  moz_inputhistory
```

but none of them contain much data (I have tried `SELECT * FROM <TABLE> ;` for all of them).

Further, if I `dump` the entire database into file `dump.sqlite`:

```
sqlite> .output dump.sqlite
sqlite> .dump
```

The file has only couple of KB:

```
$ ls -lh
total 1.2M
-rw------- 1 martin martin  39K Sep  8 19:01 dump.sqlite
-rw------- 1 martin martin 1.2M Sep  8 07:24 places.sqlite
```

I am aware of the `vacuum` command in sqlite3. I did that, but it has no effect. The database file is still same size.

How can I investigate why the database file is so big, and what does it contain ?

Comment: Are you attempting to vacuum the file while Firefox is running? Mine is 10MB while Firefox is running, and would not change until I quit Firefox and ran the vaccum against the database while not in use. Immediately after starting Firefox, it again jumped to 10MB (from 3MB post-vacuum). I suspect that Firefox may be pre-allocating space for performance - see [this recommendation they make for performance](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance/Avoid_SQLite_In_Your_Next_Firefox_Feature#How_to_Best_Use_SQLite_If_You_Really_Need_To)

Comment: @alroc - no, I am working with the file-copy offline. Firefox is not running.

Comment: The file is not just the data inside it. There's some overhead in there. Check the file format for SQLite databases: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

Comment: @Randolph West - thanks, but how can I investigate this "overhead" data ? How I see what is in the file?

Comment: I would use a hex editor, and the file format link I posted as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I had a file that was around 30 MB, and issued the `vacuum full` (not the normal VACUUM as it has the same effect that the Postgres behavior) for reducing its size. After the operation the file got sized 22 MB. I'm pasting the stats of each execution, which shows the differences in between (you will see more failures due to size for the VF).

```
sqlite> vacuum;
Successful lookaside attempts:       3690
Lookaside failures due to size:      913
Lookaside failures due to OOM:       0

sqlite> vacuum full;
Successful lookaside attempts:       6509
Lookaside failures due to size:      1621
Lookaside failures due to OOM:       0
```

The command `.dbinfo` will provide some information as the *database page size* and its *count*. Database pages are variable as specified in [the file format doc page](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#cell_payload_overflow_pages) (this link contains all the internal structures).

For investigating the contents you can use [sqlite_stats1](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#stat1tab) (the link contains the specifications of this table) table, which will be created after the ANALYZE:

```
analyze;
select * from sqlite_stat1;
```